# Make multiple targets for all subdirectories

Tags: makefile

My directory structure is the following (of course the `src/` subdirectories also contain files, but these are not important right now):

```
examples/
├───testprog1/
│   ├───bin/
│   ├───obj/
│   ├───src/
│   └───Makefile
├───testprog2/
│   ├───bin/
│   ├───obj/
│   ├───src/
│   └───Makefile
└───Makefile
```

The `Makefile`'s in `testprog1/` and `testprog2/` look similar to this one:

```
OBJECTS_FILES=$(subst .cpp,.o,$(subst src/,obj/,$(wildcard src/*.cpp)))

bin/testprog1.exe: $(OBJECTS_FILES)
    g++ -o $@ $^

obj/%.o: src/%.cpp
    g++ -c -o $@ $^

clean:
    rm -f obj/*.o
    rm -f bin/meanTest.exe
```

They work perfectly fine alone, but if I want to build all examples at once, it would be better to use the `Makefile` in `examples/` for that. What should it look like? Of course, it has to have the targets `all` and `clean` it will execute for all subdirectories. I also would like to avoid for-loops because I heard that they prevent `make` from using parallel processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a recipe run in the background by appending an `&` to the end, which would allow you to build in parallel, but that's messy as your target could complete before the background tasks have finished running, which could cause dependency issues, so we'll steer clear of that.

A better solution would be to create a new rule for each subdir:

```
.PHONY: testprog1 testprog2

testprog1 testprog2:
    $(MAKE) -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)

all clean: testprog1 testprog2
```

If you do a `make clean`, then `$(MAKECMDGOALS)` will be `clean`.   It will build both `testprog1` and `testprog2` with this target.   Notice that because `testprog1` and `testprog2` are directory names, you have to declare them as phonies, as their timestamp will change when you build them.

You could also specify the target as `%: testprog1 testprog2` if you wanted any command (save `testprog1` or `testprog2`) to be passed down to the submakes.